# Radeon 5770 black screen issues on Mac Pro

Tags: drivers, graphics, radeon, amd-graphics

Hey awesome ubuntu guys & girls!

I have installed Ubuntu 18.04 on my Mac Pro 2010 on a separate partition. I now have a triple boot with windows and High Sierra.

Unfortunately, the Graphics Card is not supported. I can only boot with "nomodeset" boot flag, otherwise I have a black screen.

The Radeon driver doesn't seem to work for me and VESA drivers (with nomodeset) are not a good alternative. Everything is laggy and has a bad performance. Since there are no official AMD drivers for 18.04 it seems as if I can't change anything here, can I?

It's an ATI Radeon 5770 with 1GB GDDR5 RAM in the Mac edition (it has a different firmware than standard 5770).

xserver-xorg-video-radeon was installed automatically by ubuntu. The installation started only with nomodeset. Without nomodeset, I had a black screen already at the installation and live boot.

lspci shows

```
05:00.0 VGA compatible controller: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD/ATI] Juniper XT [Radeon HD 5770]
```

I searched all places I can, but somehow I can't find people having this bug. Maybe most Mac Users just use their macOS.

Thanks a lot for your help!